# How to obtain single planer image from a multi planer image?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have an image which is a two planer image. I have to obtain the single planer perspective of the image.

The image is in form of like this image,

I am able to detect the outer black boundary of the image using edge detection and contour finding.

[image]

So I have the co-ordinates of the contour.

I have tried warpPerspective method of opencv but could not able to get the desired result.

Now my question is how can I obtain the approx original shape of the box from this and change the perspective of the code to single planer image.

Comment: Have you tried [perspective-transformation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#perspective-transformation)

Comment: warpPerspective works with only 4 points that's why it considering the curve as straight line and cutting out the portion of the image.